# Validate with parsleyjs onkeyup

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

While using ParsleyJS to validate my forms, I noticed the validations are performed only after the users clicks the submit button.
**Is there a way to perform the validation while the user is typing the input?** Something like an onkeyup() event.

Comment: please share the program you used, and errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This data-parsley-trigger="keyup"

Comment: You can also try data-parsley-trigger="change" so it'll trigger when you leave the field after typing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `trigger` option to `'input'`.